# Ubuntu 15.10: Copy password from keepass2 to PhpStorm

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-15.10, keepass

Hello I use *KeePass2* for saving my passwords and *PhpStorm* for coding.

When I want to past (<kbd>Strg+V</kbd>) a password from *KeePass* to the *PhpStorm* terminal it doesn't work.

When I past the same password in my normal *Ubuntu* terminal it works perfect.

I read you have to install the package `xsel` if you want it to work but in my case it is still not working and the package is installed.

Has someone an solution?

Comment: Can you paste another text? Does *Right click + Paste* work?

Comment: Yes I can past other text in PhpStorm. But when I copy textes from Keepass and then Right click + Paste is disabled like I would not copy any text (but in other programs i can paste the text from keepass).

Answer (score 0):

If you use KeePass database file to store passwords, you can easely set password for that file, save and then open in KeePass manager, or migrate to other PHPStorm.

1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings
   | Passwords, enter new master password and save.
2. Open /.PhpStorm2017.1/config/c.kdbx (in "Keepass 2" or "Keeweb") with saved master password.
3. Here it is!

See answer here
[Retrieve saved (hidden) SSH password from PhpStorm 2017.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431973/retrieve-saved-hidden-ssh-password-from-phpstorm-2017-1/44467433#44467433)
See this too 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170108